# vba code to download each attachment in outlook inbox to C drive on computer

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

Every day I receive an email externally in my outlook inbox with subject "company servicing - 2023-06-13 reports". This email is sent from Company Servicing servicing_qa@Company.com.

There are 4 csv attachments within this email with different name, `company_tx__20230613.csv` `company_tb_20230613.csv` `company_rem_20230613.csv` and `company_pos_20230613.csv`

I want to have a VBA code to download those 4 csv files to the specific folder in our LAN drive `(M:\Company\received)`

What I expect is I only look for emails received today (say June 13, 2023), and if there is email sent from `Company Servicing <servicing_qa@Company.com>` and subject is `company servicing - 2023-06-13 reports`, and there are attachments in it, download them to `(M:\Company\received)`

I've tried to define some variables and the following is part of my code. It looks the code can look through emails received today

```
olFldr.Items.restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= """ & Format(Date, "ddddd") & """")
```

works well, but

```
InStr(olMail.Subject, "company servicing - 2023-06-13 reports")
```

and

```
olMail.SenderEmailAddress = "servicing_qa@Company.com"
```

do not work

Any suggesstions?

Comment: Would help a lot to post your full code, and explain what specific problem(s) you're having with it.  "do not work" is not a very useful description.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple restrictions into a single query:

```
set restrictedItems = olFldr.Items.restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" & Format(Date, "ddddd") & "' AND [Subject] = 'company servicing - 2023-06-13 reports' AND [SenderEmailAddress] = 'servicing_qa@Company.com'")
```

See [Items.Restrict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all conditions into the single search criteria string. For that you can use logical operators like `AND`. For filtering by dates you can use the following search string:

```
    'This filter uses urn:schemas:httpmail namespace 
    strFilter = AddQuotes("urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived") _ 
    & " > '" & datStartUTC & "' AND " _ 
    & AddQuotes("urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived") _ 
    & " < '" & datEndUTC & "'"
```

When you deal with string properties you need to pay attention that your search term can be a part of the Subject line, for example. For that reason you need to use DASL syntax which supports the matching of prefixes, phrases, and substrings in a string property using content indexer keywords `ci_startswith` and `ci_phrasematch`, and the keyword like.

```
criteria = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) _ 
& "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) _ 
& " ci_phrasematch 'question'"
```

And for the sender:

```
criteria = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) _ 
& "urn:schemas:httpmail:senderemail" & Chr(34) _ 
& " like '%servicing_qa@Company.com%'"
```

So, you just need to combine them together using the `AND` operator.

But a better yet way to handle such email is when they are received into your Inbox. The `NewMailEx` event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` string to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item. So, you can check all the required properties when an item is received and save attached files if required without filtering items in the folder.